# "react" Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-key-index

An error seems to occur because the key value is not entered in the map function, but I do not know how to modify the code.

The array is structured like this:

```
    const tabContArr=[
        {
            tabTitle:(
                <span className={activeIndex===0 ? "is-active" : ""} onClick={()=>tabClickHandler(0)}>0</span>
            ),
         
        },
        {
            tabTitle:(
                <span className={activeIndex===1 ? "is-active" : ""} onClick={()=>tabClickHandler(1)}>1</span>
            ),
           
        },
        {
            tabTitle:(
                <span className={activeIndex===2 ? "is-active" : ""} onClick={()=>tabClickHandler(2)}>2</span>
            ),
          
        },
        {
            tabTitle:(
                <span className={activeIndex===3 ? "is-active" : ""} onClick={()=>tabClickHandler(3)}>3</span>
            ),
           
        }
    ];
```

An error occurs in the map function part.

```
   {tabContArr.map((section)=>{
                return section.tabTitle
            })}
```

Comment: If you add key-prop to those spans, it might work., so like <span className={activeIndex===3 ? "is-active" : ""} key = "1" The key needs to be unique for each element so that react knows how to update and render list-like data if something changes in it. It doesn't want to render the whole list again every time you add something to it for example, so it needs the keys to know that.

Comment: This doesn't look like a very efficient way of approaching the problem. All your spans are identical with the exception of the argument you're passing into the function.

Comment: https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is not the right way.
If you have data, instead of passing the ReactElement into the array you should pass it into the map function like this:

```
{tabContArr.map((tab, index)=>{
      return <span 
         className={activeIndex === index ? "is-active" : ""} 
         onClick={()=>tabClickHandler(index)} 
         key={`tab-${index}`}>index</span>
})}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using index as a key, it can cause problems and will throw a console error. You should be using some kind of unique ID or something which will not repeated in the map.

Comment: But if the list is not going to be updated, reordered and be static as it is and you do not have item id then using key as index is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) with a `key` attribute as mentioned in [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments)

```
{tabContArr.map((section, index)=>{
    return <React.Fragment key={`section-tab-${index}`}>{section.tabTitle}</React.Fragment>
 })}
```